# Destroy session across all sub domains

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

The main domain is `.xyz.com` which is currently developed in Codeigniter framework.

I have created a sub-domain `abc` for deployment of code developed in Core PHP.

I have successfully implemented the SSO (Single Sign On) functionality by creating a cookie from Codeigniter Website for CorePHP code (on sub-domain).

Now I have to destroy the session across all sub domains.

I have an idea of deleting cookie (which was created for signing on the user in Core PHP application) in Codeigniter logout method. But I am unable to access the `$_SESSION` in Codeigniter which is still available in Core PHP application.

```
public function logout() {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    /*Some code to destroy the session of phpBB forum*/
    ....
    ....
    ....

    //deleting the cookie for Core PHP application
    if (isset($_COOKIE['nzr'])) {
        setcookie("nzr", null, 0, $this->config->item('cookie_path'), $this->config->item('cookie_domain'), 0);
    }
    setcookie('connections', null, 0, '/', $this->config->item('cookie_domain'), 0);

    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION); // --> Here I am getting nothing (a blank array)
    die;
}
```

But `$_SESSION` is still available in Core PHP app. How I can destroy this session from Codeigniter.

It seems that both sessions (The codeigniter and Core PHP) saving mechanism is different, that's why I am unable to destroy both the session.

If I use to print session user_id using `$this->session->userdata('user_id')`, I got the output but it is not available if I print `$_SESSION` using `print_r($_SESSION)`.

Comment: $_SESSION is available from the start to the end of the current PHP script. If you destroy the session the global $_SESSION variable will stay untouched on current load and will be empty on NEXT load :) so if you are killing the session you can update(unset) and the $_SESSION variable at the same place..

Comment: It seems that both sessions (The codeigniter and Core PHP) saving mechanism is different, that's why I am unable to destroy both the session.

Comment: why you are setting nzr and connections cookies instead of unsetting them